# Epplus add one value over a range

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

How can I add one text value of a range of cells?  Currently, I have the following code snippet:

```
ExcelRange oRngheader1 = oSheet.Cells["A2:B2"];
oSheet.Cells["A2:B2"].Value= "Division Budgets";
```

Which places the value 'Division Budgets' in both cell A2 and Cell B2; however, I wish this value to span both A2 to B2.

Comment: I found out how this is done.  You have to merge the ExcelRange object.

Answer (score 1):

```
ExcelRange oRngheader1 = oSheet.Cells["A2:B2"];
oSheet.Cells["A2"].Value= "Division Budgets";
oRngheader1.Merge = true;
```

It's important to put the value in the top-left-most cell to ensure that it's not lost when you merge.